Trying to find a French film I watched 5-10 years ago on Netflix
5-10 years ago, I watched a French movie on Netflix. I believe it had a French title as well, and I recall thinking it was a rather niche film, even at the time.
Here's what I remember (potentially inaccurate):

It was about a young man, who I believe got mixed up with some bad people. I think he had a brother or close friend.
There was a mechanic shop with a small junkyard behind it. I seem to remember several scenes taking place there throughout the movie.
I think there was a bad guy who was bald, and potentially a mechanic at that same shop.
At the climax of the film, I think there was a tense scene where the main character hid under a car in that junkyard.
I seem to remember at least one scene where they stopped on a road with open fields on both sides - I think the mechanic shop may have been near said fields.
For some reason I think I remember the cover having a man standing with a pale green field behind him. I'm not 100% on this detail, however.

I've tried searching online, going through lists of French films, and checking my Netflix watch history. Unfortunately, I stopped using Netflix years ago, and they deleted my account.
I realise this isn't much detail to work with, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Was the movie set in France, or somewhere else in the world?  Was the movie an action movie, a thriller, a drama, or a comedy or somewhere in between?

Was the movie released around the time that you saw it 5–10 years ago, or was it noticeably old at the time?  Was it set in something resembling the present day?

I guess I'd classify it as a thriller, based on the little bits I remember - I think it was slow-paced.

I don't recall where in the world it was set, but based on what I remember, I think it would have been somewhere European. It was set in the present day, and the movie seemed relatively new when I watched it.
